# WinForms: Proper way to change number of rows in a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: .net, winforms, desktop-application

i'm trying to change the number of rows in a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) programatically (sometimes it needs to be four, sometimes five, and rarely six).

Unfortunatly changing the number of rows does not keep the [`RowStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowstyles.aspx) collection in sync, so you are then not able to set the height of the newly added rows. The following test code demonstrates this fact:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TableLayoutPanels start with 2 rows by default.
    Debug.Assert(tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count == 
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);

    //Cannot remove rows
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
    Debug.Assert(tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count == 
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);

}
```

The second assertion fails.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TableLayoutPanels start with 2 rows by default.
    Debug.Assert(tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count == 
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);

    //Cannot add rows
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 6;
    Debug.Assert(tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count == 
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);
}
```

The second assertion fails.

So what's the proper programatic way to set the [`RowCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowcount.aspx) property of a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)?

Comment: @TheBlastOne Nope; stilll "Closed as Postponed"

Answer (score 7):

This issue was reported to Microsoft in 2005, and they acknowledge it's a bug<strike>, but they were "*still evaluating our options here*"</strike> Microsoft has decided not to fix it ("Closed").

**[TableLayoutPanel Rows and RowStyles do not correspond.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=122017)**

**Description**

> When you create a tableLayoutPanel,
>   and new rows are created (either by
>   adding rows in the program or setting
>   the RowCount property), new RowStyles
>   are not added to the control.
>   Additionally, if I add new Row Styles,
>   the number of rows is increased, but
>   not to the same number: if I start
>   with two Rows and two RowStyles, set
>   Rowcount to 4, and then add two
>   RowStyles (in design view), the
>   Rowcount has set to 6. It seems more
>   intuitive for the ordinality of the
>   RowStyles collection to match the
>   current RowCount.

### Comments

Posted by Microsoft on 10/24/2005 at 6:07 PM

> This issue has been reactivated as we begin planning for the next version of Visual Studio. Over the coming months we will reconsider feedback that was previously postponed. We welcome your comments and participation in this process.

Posted by Microsoft on 6/27/2005 at 6:49 AM

> The Microsoft Sub-status is now
>   "Reproduced"
>
> Thanks for reporting this bug, we have
>   been able to repro this issue and are
>   investigating.
>
> Thank you, Prabhu, VS2005 Product
>   Team.

Posted by Microsoft on 6/27/2005 at 5:55 PM

> Thankyou for reporting this issue.
>   This is a peculiarity in our runtime
>   object model that doesn't translate
>   well to design time. At runtime the
>   RowCount and ColCount really mean
>   minRowCount and minColCount in terms
>   of autogrow, because rows/cols don't
>   need a supporting style. At design
>   time we try to simplify that and keep
>   a near 1:1 correspondence between
>   styles and rows/cols. In this case,
>   you are seeing by design runtime
>   behavior. We already have a bug
>   tracking this issue and are still
>   evaluating our options here. Thanks
>   again for contributing to a better
>   Whidbey.

Posted by Microsoft on 7/6/2005 at 3:43 PM

> Thankyou for
>   reporting this issue. This is a
>   peculiarity in our runtime object
>   model that we have chosen to not
>   address at design time. At runtime the
>   RowCount and ColCount really mean
>   minRowCount and minColCount in terms
>   of autogrow, because rows/cols don't
>   require a supporting style. At design
>   time we generally try to simplify that
>   and keep a near 1:1 correspondence
>   between styles and rows/cols. In the
>   case of rowSpan or colSpan on a table
>   layot panel with autogrow you can get
>   into a state where
>   rows/rowcount/rowstyles are out of
>   sync. To avoid this, simply add the
>   columns/rows you need first, then set
>   the controls *span property. Thanks.

Posted by Microsoft on 10/24/2005 at 6:07 PM

> This issue has been reactivated as we
>   begin planning for the next version of
>   Visual Studio. Over the coming months
>   we will reconsider feedback that was
>   previously postponed. We welcome your
>   comments and participation in this
>   process.
>
> -- Visual Studio Team

Comment: Every page I've ever seen on that site ends up with no response or 'Uhhh... Maybe later'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new `RowStyle` and then adding it using the `tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add` method?

Comment: This doesn't work. Assume: start with two rows, and then add two styles, you'll end up with six rows.